Why must I commit after the ALTER TABLE DDL to make changes visible?
If I execute this in DBeaver:
alter table classes alter column reference set not null;

on my local database which only I have open in DBeaver, it completes successfully.
But then I can't open the table in the explorer, and the column is still showing as nullable.
If I try to close DBeaver, it says there is an open transaction, but I don't think there is.
However, if I run commit, suddenly everything works, I can view the table and the column is showing as not null.
I thought DDL statements didn't have the concept of commit and rollback: do I have to commit after every one in my Flyway update scripts?

Some DBMS will commit automatically after ddl operations, but postgres is not one of them.
Check the settings in dbeaver, you may have auto commit disabled. In the version of dbeaver I checked it is located here:

Regarding flyway, it will do a commit at the end of each file if no error occured. In general, do not put explicit commit statements in your migration files, it will mess with the idempotent property of the migration files. Assume a migration files like:
CREATE mytable t (x int);

COMMIT;

-- deliberate syntax error
CREATTE mytable u (x int);

Flyway will rollback the transaction for the schema version on the syntax error, but the table t exists due to the commit. If you fix the syntax error and run flyway again it will fail because t already exists.
Flyway uses two transactions for each migration file. One transaktion puts an exclusive lock on the schema history table, the other transaction runs the migration file. If the migration succeds, the first transaction inserts the new version into the history table and commits, i.e releases the lock on the history table.
Having DDL under transaction control is a good thing. For DBMS that does not support this you need to implement undo files, which is a pain. For DBMS that support this, flyway can just rollback the transaction. Needless to say, a lot  easier

Do no disable autocommit in DBeaver (or other clients). I have seen  database get into trouble because of that.

@LaurenzAlbe, not sure if that is directed to me or the op, but I certainly agree unless it is against a development machine where you want to try something out. I've seen cases where squirrell turned of auto commit by it self (according to the person running it) against a production database. Putting a lock in a central table caused massive lock timeout for almost everyone trying to access the database.


I thought DDL statements didn't have the concept of commit and rollback

You were wrong.

do I have to commit after every one in my flyway update scripts?

You only need to commit when you want other sessions to see the changes.

Oracle have the concept of committing current session when performing a DDL.
